# OMNET++: error in module cModule during network setup

Tags: c++11, omnet++

I'm trying to run my first Castalia/WSN simulation (testRouting) in Omnet++ including folders with .ned and c++/h files (TestRouting.h , TestRouting.cc and TestRouting.ned) and the .ini file and I have fixed errors that appears at the omnet IDE.

When I start a simulation I receive the error:

**Error in module (cModule) SN.node[0].Communication (id=10) during network setup: Submodule Routing: no module type named 'TestRouting' found that implements module interface node.communication.routing.iRouting(not in the loaded NED files ?), at omnetpp-4.6/samples/castalia/src/node/communication/CommunicationModule.ned:32.**

I already tried to rebuild OMNeT++ with Castalia as I have read in other proposed solutions, but it didn’t help.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because your `TestRouting` module in TestRouting.ned does not properly implement the `node.communication.routing.iRouting` module interface.

Your code in the TestRouting.ned file should at least look something like this:

```
simple TestRouting like node.communication.routing.iRouting
```

or something similar.

In short: your model code is incorrect...